# How to use $.mobile.loading(); with googlemap

Tags: jquery, load, message

I am building a web application with jquerymobile and phone gap.
In case of low connection, but even with any kind of connection speed, I would like to have a loading message.
This particurlarely on slow speed connection (edge) and while googlemap is loading or refreshing.
I notice that the googlemap picture take a moment to be deisplayed.

I saw there is a jquery method

```
$.mobile.loading('show');$.mobile.loading('hide');
```

I tried the follwoing to have it on all pages

```
$(document).live('pagebeforeload', function(){
    $.mobile.loading('show');
})

$(document).live('pageload', function(){
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
})
```

But I did not see any differenece and load message.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank